# Will this add_node function cause memory issues?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have written a recursive function to insert a new node in a Binary Search Tree. The function is given below.

```
void add_node(node *it, int val)
{
    node * temp = new node;
    temp->data=val;
    temp->left=NULL;
    temp->right=NULL;
    if(root==NULL)
    {

        root=temp;
    }
    else if(it->data > val)
    {
        if(it->left==NULL)
        {

            it->left=temp;
            return;
        }
        else
            add_node(it->left, val);
    }

    else
    {
        if(it->right==NULL)
        {

            it->right=temp;
            return;
        }
        else
            add_node(it->right, val);
    }
}
```

This function creates a temp node every time it is recursively called. Will this cause some problem(related to memory) if height of the BST is large?

Comment: You have to profile/test for a specific area.

Comment: What happens to temp when neither the current node nor its children are leaves? You might want to consider looking into std::unique_ptr to make memory management easier.

Comment: This is very convoluted.  If you want to add a new node, you create the new node one time and one time only.  Then figure out how to place that new node in the tree.

Comment: Yes, it will leak; one node for every hop in the tree except the last. Don't create a new node until you finally discover where it will be hung. Unrelated, this is much easier with a reference-to-pointer as the first argument type.

Comment: This uses tail recursion, and all tail recursions can be rewritten as a loop. That would also mean you don't have to remove the leaks from unused nodes, since every call would use that created node (after looping to find where to put it)

Answer (score 2):

> This function creates a temp node every time it is recursively called.

That node allocation isn't temporary; it's outright leaked. The only one that is retained is the *last* one. Any traversal requiring *more* than one hop will, in fact, leak the node allocation in any preceding recursive calls in the activation stack.

Two things make this problem solvable.

1. Don't allocate a node until you know where it is to be hung.
2. Related, don't code against some external `root`. Use a reference-to-pointer as the input argument type allow you to refer to actual pointers (not just the addresses they hold) directly in the tree. This includes the `root` pointer.

Assuming a `node` structure that looks like this (with paranoia of deleting copy ctor and assignment):

```
struct node
{
    node(int val)
        : value(val)
        , left(nullptr)
        , right(nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "node::node(" << value << ")\n";
    }

    node(const node&) = delete;
    node& operator=(const node&) = delete;

    int value;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};
```

We can craft a simple node insertion like this:

```
// note reference-to-pointer as first arg type
void add_node(node *& refp, int value) 
{
    if (refp == nullptr)
    {
        refp = new node(value);
    }
    else if (value < refp->value)
    {
        add_node(refp->left, value);
    }
    else
    {
        add_node(refp->right, value);
    }
}
```

That's it. One allocation once we finally know where things go. No special case for some external `root` pointer, and considerably easier to read and understand.

---

**Full Example**

Adding the `node` and `add_node` definitions from above, an inorder print traversal, and a `free_tree` to clean things up, an example is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

struct node
{
    node(int val)
        : value(val)
        , left(nullptr)
        , right(nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "node::node(" << value << ")\n";
    }

    node(const node&) = delete;
    node& operator=(const node&) = delete;

    int value;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};

void add_node(node *& refp, int value)
{
    if (refp == nullptr)
    {
        refp = new node(value);
    }
    else if (value < refp->value)
    {
        add_node(refp->left, value);
    }
    else
    {
        add_node(refp->right, value);
    }
}

void inorder(const node* root)
{
    if (root)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        std::cout << root->value << ' ';
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

void free_tree(node *& root)
{
    if (root)
    {
        free_tree(root->left);
        free_tree(root->right);
        delete root;
        root = nullptr;
    }
}

int main()
{
    node *root = nullptr;

    std::mt19937 rng{ std::random_device{}() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1, 99);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        add_node(root, dist(rng));

    inorder(root);
    std::cout.put('\n');

    free_tree(root);
}
```

**Output** {varies, obviously)

```
node::node(79)
node::node(28)
node::node(39)
node::node(82)
node::node(10)
node::node(11)
node::node(22)
node::node(4)
node::node(19)
node::node(85)
node::node(38)
node::node(66)
node::node(45)
node::node(15)
node::node(23)
node::node(73)
node::node(52)
node::node(45)
node::node(73)
node::node(84)
4 10 11 15 19 22 23 28 38 39 45 45 52 66 73 73 79 82 84 85
```